# Sendmail configs and logs look correct, but I get no mail

Tags: ubuntu, sendmail, gmail

I used [this](http://linuxconfig.org/configuring-gmail-as-sendmail-email-relay) tutorial to config `sendmail` on Ubuntu. Followed every step and when I test it, it seems to have worked, but I get no mail (not even on the spam folder)

Below is the log for a test message:

```
050 >>> MAIL From:<christian@UX-BLUEROOM.localhost> SIZE=345 AUTH=<>
050 250 2.1.0 OK ek1sm23505399vdc.28 - gsmtp
050 >>> RCPT To:<######@gmail.com>
050 250 2.1.5 OK ek1sm23505399vdc.28 - gsmtp
050 >>> DATA
050 354  Go ahead ek1sm23505399vdc.28 - gsmtp
050 >>> .
050 250 2.0.0 OK 1401150762 ek1sm23505399vdc.28 - gsmtp
050 <########@gmail.com>... Sent (OK 1401150762 ek1sm23505399vdc.28 - gsmtp)
250 2.0.0 s4R0WdYN007263 Message accepted for delivery
######@gmail.com... Sent (s4R0WdYN007263 Message accepted for delivery)
```

And this is my `/var/log/mail.log`

```
May 26 21:32:39 UX-BLUEROOM sendmail[7262]: s4R0Wdxq007262: from=christian, size=105,     class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201405270032.s4R0Wdxq007262@UX-BLUEROOM.localhost>, relay=christian@localhost
May 26 21:32:40 UX-BLUEROOM sm-mta[7263]: s4R0WdYN007263: from=<christian@UX-BLUEROOM.localhost>, size=345, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201405270032.s4R0Wdxq007262@UX-BLUEROOM.localhost>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
May 26 21:32:41 UX-BLUEROOM sm-mta[7263]: STARTTLS=client, relay=gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA, bits=128/128
May 26 21:32:42 UX-BLUEROOM sm-mta[7263]: s4R0WdYN007263: to=<######@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<christian@UX-BLUEROOM.localhost> (1000/1000), delay=00:00:02, xdelay=00:00:02, mailer=relay, pri=30345, relay=gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com. [173.194.75.109], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (OK 1401150762 ek1sm23505399vdc.28 - gsmtp)
May 26 21:32:42 UX-BLUEROOM sendmail[7262]: s4R0Wdxq007262: to=#####@gmail.com, ctladdr=christian (1000/1000), delay=00:00:03, xdelay=00:00:03, mailer=relay, pri=30105, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (s4R0WdYN007263 Message accepted for delivery)
```

Answer (score 1):

Google will not accept your messages without a valid domain.  They'll claim to accept them, but this is mainly to prevent spammers from figuring it out.

I know this isn't for Google, but it's the most comprensive source of information for properly configuring your mail server that I've found: http://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx

Comment: So I can't relay with Google?

Comment: Almost certainly not without authentication, and definitely not from your 'christian@UX-BLUEROOM.localhost' email address.

Comment: But I have authentication configured, it is a part of the tutorial I mentioned.

Comment: Gmail silently drop the message if he sure it's a spam. If gmail doubts message goes to the "Spam" folder. Looks like that in your case gmail has no doubts.